# How do I reduce latency while playing World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I live in the country and have a satellite dish as my internet connection/provider.

I constantly deal with almost 2000 latency.

What I am wondering is if there is anything that I could do to improve the latency on my end?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is. This is a general purpose latency fix, that can have a small to medium sized effect on your latency, depending on several factors.

It's known as the [Leatrix Latency Fix](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info13581-LeatrixLatencyFix.html).

It [works by changing](http://www.wowinterface.com/portal.php?&id=731&pageid=246) the packet buffer on your OS from 2 to 1. This increases traffic, but reduces latency by removing the wait time for confirmation calls under certain conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Get a terrestrial ISP.

The reason your latency is so high is that your signal must travel up to the satellite (it's in SPACE) and back, for each direction of your communication. [The trip there and back adds at least half a second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Internet_access#Signal_latency), so the Internet round-trip is somewhere in the neighborhood of 1 to 1.5 seconds. That's *just* for the satellite uplink/downlink. Add in the rest of the Internet route and you're pretty much screwed.